# How to format the datetime in c#?

Tags: datetime

I got the current datetime by using the following code.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

But it is in the format of, **2015-02-23 17:25:07.123**
how to convert this to the format of, **"02/23/2015"**?

Comment: [Use `dt.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc319767.aspx).

Comment: What does this have to do with nunit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: There's no need to use a composite format string here - unless it's being performed as part of an existing formatting operation, calling `dt.ToString` and passing in the format is simpler, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> "But it is in the format of"

No it isn't. It's just a `DateTime`. If you want a particular text representation, call `ToString` on it, specifying the format. For example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formatted = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

You might also want to specify the culture to use for formatting - that way you could just say "Use the right short date format" for example.

See the MSDN pages on [custom date/time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4) and [standard date/time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1) for more details.